# Item level status in magento 2 via Netsuite

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order, order-status, status

We have used `Netsuite` for `items shipment` tracking, now I don't know on which table of Magento 2, Netsuite updates item level status.

Like for an order, there can be multiple items, and I have to show the item level status(shipment status). But I don't know which table entry goes.

`sales_orders` has order level status.

Comment: Do you mean every item status? or order status? Because I think the shipment status is for every order, not every item.

Comment: @magefms  yes that's what netsuite do item level status but I don't know in which table of Magento it updates I tried looking sales_order_items but no luck

Comment: try to check in `sales_shipment_item` there might be an extra column for the item shipment status